# Recyclerview duplicates data onscroll

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview that contains Textview and Edittext on each row. User type input on each row and it's working fine unless the user scrolls down or up, data type on input field gets duplicated on other rows. For example, if I type on row number one and scroll down to row 10 or 15 and then scroll right back to row one then the data type on row one gets print on other rows like 8-14 etc. How to disable this behavior of recyclerview

MyAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val itemList: MutableList<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        lateinit var onTextUpdated: (String) -> Unit
        var txtLabel: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel)
        var etValue: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etValue)

        init { // TextChanged listener added only once.
            etValue.doAfterTextChanged { editable ->
                val text = editable.toString()
                onTextUpdated(text)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_comment, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtLabel.text = itemList[position]
        holder.onTextUpdated = { text -> // each time holder is bound, new listener will be assigned
            try {
                updateItem(
                    position,
                    text
                ) // update cached value
                holder.txtLabel.text = text // update label

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                println(ex.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    fun updateItem(position: Int, item: String) {
        itemList[position] = item
    }
}
```

Even in my adapter, I am updating the list on item position. Kindly guide how can I achieve this. I want recyclerview to stop duplicating data on scrolling

Comment: The edit text just stores and restores the last state. You need to reset it in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Can you share the example or point out where to fix it

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder`, `holder.etValue.text = itemList[position]`

Comment: ```holder.setIsRecyclable(false)``` add in ```onBindViewHolder```